# Can I use formulas in select case

Tags: excel, select, range, case

I have a function with the following select case statement.  The function does not work if I have an Excel in the condition section.

Like:   `Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M50")`

The function works if I put in a value for the condition,
 such as:         `Case Is >= 5`

The select is shown below.  Is using a formula not allowed? Is there a work around?

```
Select Case distance


Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M50")
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n50").Value

Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M51").Value
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n51").Value

Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M52").Value
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n52").Value

Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M53").Value
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n53").Value

Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M54").Value
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n54").Value

Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M55").Value
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n55").Value

Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M56").Value
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n56").Value

Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M57").Value
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n57").Value

Case Is >= Sheets("list").Range("M58").Value
RightPlace = Sheets("list").Range("n58").Value



End Select
```

Comment: Try adding the `.Value` to the first `Case` statement.

Comment: Adding the .value did not work- but thank you @RBarryYoung  , Dave

Comment: What does *have an Excel* mean?  Excel is a program sold by Microsoft.  How do you have that in a macro?

Comment: I should have said - Excel Worksheet reference, my mistake for rushing @rBarryYoung

Comment: @Dave Maybe you should take a breath, take the rush out of things, and calmly consider what has been offered. Also, take the [Tour] and then mark the answer to your question instead of discussing and arguing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why use a Case statement at all? You are looking up data in spreadsheet cells, so you might as well use

```
RightPlace = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(distance, Sheets("list").Range("M50:N58"), 2, False)
```

Comment: This is a good idea but l would have to rearrange my list to meet the sort in ascending order of vlookup

Comment: If you use False as the fourth argument of a Vlookup, the data does not have to be sorted. Sorted data is only expected when the fourth parameter is TRUE or omitted.

Comment: The vlookup works I needed to sort because did not have exact matches as you point out I have to use false as forth argument.@teylyn

Comment: You don't use much punctuation. Therefore, the comment after mine is hard to interpret. If you want to perform an exact lookup, ensure that the fourth argument is "FALSE". It will do what your `Select Case` code does, only in one line. Confirm that that works and mark the answer.

Comment: Below is what works RightPlace = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(distance, Sheets("list").Range("M50:N58"), 2, True)